# Django -- How to call a form submit view into dataupload view

Tags: python, django

I have a Form submission view and a dataupload view. I want to save the form and be redirected to the upload page to upload the file.

I tried return the form submission view in the upload view. The form is getting saved but i am getting MultiValueDictKey error

```py
def uploaddata(request):

        return Metadata_submission(request)

        if request.method == 'POST':

                form = uploadmetaform(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        return redirect('file_list')
        else:
                form = uploadmetaform()
        return render(request, 'uploaddata.html', {
                'form': form
        })
```

This is my form submission view:

```py
def Metadata_submission(request):
        print("Metadata Submitted")

        Authors_Name = request.POST["Authors_Name"]
        Affliations = request.POST["Affliations"]
        Dataset_Creation_Date = request.POST["Dataset_Creation_Date"]


        Metadata_var = Metadataform(Authors_Name=Authors_Name, 
        Affliations=Affliations,Dataset_Creation_Date=Dataset_Creation_Dat)
        Metadata_var.save()
```

MultiValueDictKeyError at /uploaddata/
'Authors_Name'

Comment: Apparently there isn't a field `Authors_Name` being submitted by your HTML form.

Comment: but anyway, your python code doesn't make sense. You have code after the `return` line that can never be reached. And your `Metadata_submission` function doesn't return anything so `uploaddata` just would return `None` (if your `Metadata_submission` didn't crash before with your error).

Comment: That is what i am asking for, i don't know how to reach the upload part after the form submission

Comment: if you first want to submit a form with data, then redirect to a new page where user can upload a page, you need to have two views and call the first view directly. So make your HTML form post to the `Metadata_submission` view (pointing the `action` URL to the url for that view instead of the `upload data` view), where you handle your post like you learned from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view) and redirect to the other view (`uploaddata`) that handles the second form.

Comment: Thank you...this is all i wanted. i didn't think of this return redirect...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use MultiValueDict's **get** method. It gives a default value if the contents don't exist. The default value would be false in this case.

```py
Authors_Name = request.POST.get("Authors_Name", False)
```

**Edit**: I see someone posted before me the same thing and you said it didn´t work.
I would suggest then adding:

```py
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

file = request.FILES['file_name']
filesystem = FileSystemStorage()
filename = filesystem.save(file.name, file)
form.save()
```

In `local_settings.py`:

```py
#The url that you want to use in your browser to prefix all uploaded file paths.
MEDIA_URL = '/path/wherever'
#Here you indicate the absolute path
MEDIA_ROOT = os.getcwd() + "/same/path/"
```

This media folder should have a `chmod 755` for DJANGO to be able to store files there.

**Edit 2**: Changed MEDIA_URL explanation based on dirkgroten's answer.

Comment: `request.POST` is a subclass of a python `dict`. [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is a standard python method for dictionaries.

Comment: Note that `request.POST` is actually a `MultiValueDict` which is defined by django to allow multiple values for the same key, so it also has a method `getlist()` which will return the list of values for a key.

Comment: @dirkgroten Working with a form, it always gives you the value of the variable or it return the default value.

Comment: I was just commenting on your question that said "I don't understand why it works like that". This has nothing to do with forms (it actually has nothing to do with Django), I'm just explaining how `get()` works and where it comes from.

Comment: Your additional Edit is not necessarily correct. If the form is a ModelForm for a model with a FileField, then there's no need to save the file explicitly since it'll be saved automatically when you save the form. We don't know what kind of form OP is using.

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry I was at work (in a break) so I replied quickly. Well, I don't know if it's gonna work for him, but it solved problems in the past in my project. Just wanting to add something that might be useful.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with OP's code. I upvoted your answer for the effort and because you're new. I don't think it'll solve the many issues in this question though :-)

Comment: Also note that your explanation of `MEDIA_URL` is not correct. MEDIA_URL is the url that you want to use in your browser to prefix all uploaded file paths. Typically it's "/media/" but it could be anything really and doesn't need to map a path on your file system at all. The Django server will map it to MEDIA_ROOT, i.e. if MEDIA_URL is "/foo/" then an image with `src` "/foo/images/photo.jpg" will be mapped to the file <MEDIA_ROOT>/images/photo.jpg. In production, you'd add that to your nginx/apache config, telling your web server how to map /foo/ to the actual location of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Authors_Name = request.POST.get('Authors_Name', False)
```

Comment: It can't give the same error, that's not possible. It might still give you an error, but not the same.